# jQuery, how to loop through an array with ajax only once

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax, loops

I have this `jQuery` function that reads the values from `wp_localize_script` declaration.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var assjs = {"action":"get_ass_counts","path":"http:\/\/localhost\/wordpress-dev\/wp-content\/plugins\/advanced-social-status","_wpnonce":"2f3686b7ca","networks":"fblike,fbshare","ajax_url":"http:\/\/localhost\/wordpress-dev\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

The parts of the query that I am most interested in is `"networks":"fblike,fbshare"`

In a separate JavaScript file I have this function:

**AJAX Script**

```
$('.advanced-social-status form').on('submit', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    // Array of social networks
    var social_networks = [assjs.networks];

    // cancel previous requests
    if (asswxhr) asswxhr.abort();

    $.each(social_networks, function(key){
        asswxhr = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: assjs.ajax_url,
            data:{
                action: assjs.action,
                _wpnonce: assjs._wpnonce,
                network: social_networks,
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                $results.html(data);
            },
            beforeSend: function() {

                $(".ass-fbshare").html('<img style="margin-left:50px;" src="'+assjs.path+'/images/ajax-loader.gif" />');
            }
        });

    });

    return false;
});
```

What I am trying to achieve is to get each individual social network function for the `"networks":"fblike,fbshare"` which I reference in jQuery as `assjs.networks` and loop through and process it once.

Currently it posts both social network objects to my PHP script which processes the ajax request.

**PHP Script**

```
$socialnetwork = trim(stripslashes($_POST['network']));
```

If I `var_dump($_POST);` in my PHP processing script I get these results:

```
array(4) {
  ["action"]=>;
  string(14) "get_ass_counts"
  ["_wpnonce"]=>;
  string(10) "2f3686b7ca"
  ["network"]=>;
  array(1) {
    [0]=>;
    string(14) "fblike,fbshare"
  }
  ["s"]=>;
  string(0) ""
}
```

Is there a way I can separate or break up the social network names in the `jQuery` file so it only passes EACH social network name once?

Thanks

Comment: so in your array social_network you have duplicates and you want to remove them?

Comment: Is there a reason you do multiple calls in Ajax? Why not do a single request with the networks to the php code and do all of the breakdowns in the php that way you will always have all of them in your php code at the same time

Comment: @Geohut, I am probably going about it the wrong way but the aim of the script is to call the `follower` count for various social networks. They can be slow in retrieving the data so I thought doing it this way might be the way.

Comment: @aktiv-coder, don't want to remove them. I want to pull each word out of the array like `fblike` and `fbshare` from the values in the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use split for it

```
   var social_networks = [assjs.networks];
   social_networks = social_networks.split(',');
```

[MDN ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

it is not the best way to make multiple ajax call's do consider Geohut suggestion.

Comment: Also side note on this after split and making one call you can use CURL calls or file_get_contents or multiple other options to call the services you need in PHP and gather data and pass back to client.

Comment: Thanks guys. Taking advise from @Geohut if I just pass the array of social networks name to the PHP processing script, would I just need a `foreach($_POST['network'] as $network)` to process each social network name individually.

Comment: once split and on send I'd recommend JSON encoding it because it is an array and easiest to send it across as such, and then on PHP do check if value isset then do json_decode($_POST['network'])

Comment: @Jason  Yes it seems ok :)

Comment: Awesome, thanks again guys. I will take your advise and only run 1 ajax query. I will post the array of names directly to the PHP script and process them this way. Thank you @aktiv-coder. Your answer is totally correct for the initial question I was asking. Just love Stackoverflow.

Comment: @aktiv-coder One last question, when splitting them, if I use the above `foreach` how do I access each name within the loop? Would it be `$network[0]`. Or would I need to separate them by using `explode`. This part throws me.

Comment: @Jason explode them and make an array, then iterate over array using foreach

Comment: @aktiv-coder I have tried `$service = explode(",", $_POST['network']);` but it gives me this warning: `Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given `. I then tried `$ser = array($service);` to make array. Then looped with `foreach($ser as $network){ each $network[0] }` but not getting it